# Determining DC Motor Characteristics From Datasheet

Tags: dc-motor, datasheet, brushed-dc-motor

I am working on a project to design a brushless DC motor that is designed to act as a replacement for an existing brushed PM DC motor from a handheld drill (supplied by an 18v 3A/hr battery).

I am trying to determine the characteristics of the existing motor. The datasheet lists the following:

```
Voltage:       18 v
Max Power:     300 W
Stall Torque:  63 Nm
No-load Speed: 300 / 600 / 1700   RPM, depending on gear
```

I believe the gear ratio for gear 1 (300 rpm) to be 76:1.  Making the rotor speed 23,000 RPM.

I have carried out testing to determine the motor constant Ke and believe it to be 0.0036.  My issue is with this Ke, to deliver the stall torque the motor would have to be supplied with 200+ amps 
(from T=I*Ke)

By assuming the maximum power point occurs at half no-load speed & half stall torque, this gives:
$$\ \frac{\text{Stall Torque}}{2}  \cdot\ \frac{\text{No-load Speed (rads/sec)}}{\text{2}} =\text{Max Power}$$ 
$$\ \frac{63}{2} \cdot\ \frac{300 \cdot\ 2\pi}{\;2  \;\;\cdot\ 60} = 494 \;W $$

Which is more than listed on the datasheet.

Basically, I can't understand how the motor produces the torque / output power listed on the datasheet.  Is it possible the datasheet lists theoretical maximums that the actual drill will never achieve, or am I not considering certain factors?

Also, how do you determine where on the torque / speed curve a motor should be designed to operate, especially when that motor will have a variable load?

Comment: The math looks fine but the assumption is wrong. A motor's "Max power" rating will normally be well below Speed/2 * Stall torque/2 because that point corresponds to 50% efficiency and thus excessive heat. It's quite normal for max rated power to be around 70% of no-load speed (and around 70% efficiency) and even then, possibly with caveats about cooling or duty cycle. Always operate a motor close to max speed with relatively low torque - that gives best efficiency because torque => current => i^2*R power losses (and heat)

Comment: no load speed = 300rpm ~ 30 rad/s * 63Nm = 1900W, /4 for max power = 475 watts = same as your figure, so your sums are OK. This is well within the same ballpark as 300W, like within a factor of 2, so if 63Nm is a transient limit, and 300W a below absolute max power sustainable for, ooh, how long?, then are as consistent as you might hope for, given the lack of full speicications about what 'Max Power' means, whether absolute max, or sustainable max.

Comment: Ok, thank you, that helps with regard to "Max Power".  

How about stall torque requiring >200A from a battery, is this feasible or will the stall torque rating never be achieved, even if only for an instant?